# C# generate JWT token, where verify signature should be placed

Tags: c#, jwt, hmac

I have code to generate JWT token:

```
 var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
 var utcNowUnix = (Int32)(utcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
 var expirationTimeUtcUnix = (Int32)(utcNow.AddHours(6).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

 var payload = new JwtPayload
                   {
                        {"sub", "xxxxxxxx"},
                        {"iat", utcNowUnix},
                        {"exp", expirationTimeUtcUnix }
                   };

 var headers = new JwtHeader
                   {
                        { "alg", "HS256" },
                        { "typ", "JWT" }
                   };

 var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(headers, payload);
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

 // Token to String so you can use it in your client
 var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(secToken);
```

Generated token looks like: `xxxx.yyyy`
When I pass the same value on the page: [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

and generate token, the format of two first parts are the same: `xxxx.yyyy.(zzzz)` but on the page `.zzzz` is generated because there is something like:

```
VERIFY SIGNATURE

HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  
) secret base64 encoded
```

How and where should I add this part of signature?

Comment: This might help: (https://docs.hidglobal.com/auth-service/Content/pages/BuildingApps/Csharp/Create_and_Sign_a_JSON_Web_Token__JWT__with_C__and__Net.htm). You need to use one of the other constructors, either the one which take in the 3 raw string values or the one which takes the signing credentials when you create your `jwtsecuritytoken`.  - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: so basically you need to add a SecurityTokenDescriptor with SigningCredential as schon in the accepted answer